# Switching to Another View, IOS

Tags: ios

I am new to the coding world but am working on an app. I have code set up so that a password is required but then I want it to go into my next view which is to take a picture. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I need help.

TestViewController.m file

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end
@implementation TestViewController


- (IBAction)enterpassword
{
    NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1234"];

    if ([passwordfield.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {
        // Password is correct
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Correct Password" message:@"Password is Correct." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Enter" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    else {
        // Password is incorrect
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect Password" message:@"Password is Incorrect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

    }

}
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [actionSeat release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end

@implementation PhotoAppViewController
@synthesize imageView,choosePhotoBtn, takePhotoBtn;

-(IBAction) getPhoto:(id) sender {
    UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    if((UIButton *) sender == choosePhotoBtn) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    } else {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }

    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}

/*
 // The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
 - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
 // Custom initialization
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

/*
 // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
 - (void)loadView {
 }
 */


/*
 // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Please remove excess code and focus on the problematic code so that people can help you easier.

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your view controller, then push it on, or you could present it modally.

like this:

```
   if ([passwordfield.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {
        // Password is correct

    PhotoAppViewController *viewController = [[[PhotoAppViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self pushViewController:PhotoAppViewController animated:YES];


    }
    else {
        // Password is incorrect
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Incorrect Password" message:@"Password is Incorrect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
```

You don't really need to put up an alert saying the password was correct... just have it work.

Comment: Okay Thank you this makes more sense now. Thank you for helping a noob

Comment: Happy to help.  I've gotten lots of good help from StackOverflow